# When user re-install the app "Restore In-App Purchases" provide new receipt?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am new with App-in-Purchase.
Just a question, I dont have server for my app. so my question Is:
If user delete the app and change the iPhone and use its same developer account to new device and install again my app, how can I know that user already purchased my app? I did some research that in this case I must do "Restore In-App Purchases" which provide again the receipt.
if it works, does restore In-App Purchases make request to the apple server?

Thank you,

Comment: You're confusing two issues. You don't need to do any receipt management in order to do Restore Previous Purchase. The only thing we need to know is whether you are using StoreKit 1 or 2

Comment: Yes, I mean. I configured in apple developer account the price with 2 weeks trial. so I configured in app the storeKit in order when the trial finish to tell the user the trial end and he/she must pay.

Comment: What you mean exactly @matt that I  don't need to do any receipt management in order to do Restore Previous Purchase? Thanks.

Comment: I mean exactly what I said. The store knows and keeps track of whether this user has purchased this item. So there is no need for you to keep track of it separately. The ability to restore purchases is built in; you don't have to do anything except have a Restore button and respond to it.

Comment: in this case what API should I call for restore button? @matt

Comment: I don't know because you didn't answer my question about which version of StoreKit you are using.

Comment: Storekit 2. I found that: SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()this method make restore the purchase.

Comment: Nope. That's StoreKit 1.

Comment: so what about storeKit 2?